# How to get image Url from Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

This function save in FireStore:
`Instance of 'Future' not url.
Without toString method it gives error 'future dynamic cant be assigned to string'.

```
 onPressed: () {
              final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
                  .ref()
                  .child('images')
                  .child('image4.jpg');
              ref.putFile(image);
              final String downloadUrl = ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
              Firestore.instance.collection('images').add({"url": downloadUrl});
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ref.getDownloadURL()` is a future so you'll need to `await` it

```dart
onPressed: () async {
    final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('images')
        .child('image4.jpg');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
    String downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    Firestore.instance.collection('images').add({"url": downloadUrl});
  }
```